# Selenium java webdriver &chromedrive cannot be resolved issues

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, java-21

Hii ✌️Why am getting is error  even after add all jar in classpath
Coming Monday I have interview so when try to recall I getting is issues

my java version is 21 ,chrome version 122 can anyone help me  it would be grateful

```
Selenium java webdriver &chromedrive cannot be <
```

[image: Errorproof here]

@manoramu39@gmail.com

Comment: `WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type` as it is not imported. Maybe it is also missing on the _Java Build Path_. Consider to use Maven to manage your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```